# BeautifulSoup returns some weird text for the <a> tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to web scraping and I'm trying to scrape data from this auction website. However, I meet this weird problem when trying to get the text of the anchor tag.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="mt50">
  <div class="head_011">
    <a id="item_event_title" href="https://www.storyltd.com/auction/auction.aspx?eid=4158">NO RESERVE AUCTION OF MODERN AND CONTEMPORARY ART  (16-17 APRIL 2019)</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
auction_info = LTD_work_soup.find('a', id = 'item_event_title').text
print(auction_info)
```

This prints out *"Back To Auction Catalogue"* instead of *'NO RESERVE AUCTION OF MODERN AND CONTEMPORARY ART  (16-17 APRIL 2019)'*, which is what I am expecting.

[Here's the link](https://www.storyltd.com/auction/item.aspx?eid=4158&amp&lotno=2) to the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can extract the `NO RESERVE AUCTION OF MODERN AND CONTEMPORARY ART (16-17 APRIL 2019)'` from the webpage:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link = 'https://www.storyltd.com/auction/item.aspx?eid=4158&amp&lotno=2'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
page_content.find("input", attrs={"id":"hdnAuctionTitle"}).attrs['value']
```

Output:

```
NO RESERVE AUCTION OF MODERN AND CONTEMPORARY ART  (16-17 APRIL 2019)
```

When you check the `page_content`, you will find out that this sentence is present in an Input Tag.

I hope it helps!