# Web Scraping: missing tags in requests content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am learning Python and one of my first project is to scrape a Dell web page to extract some data to store it in Zabbix.

Basically, I need to extract the warranty information about some servers we have. 
This is the code I got so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cadhs1/product-support/servicetag/0-NE9lVXI4NlpmbjFtRHJBbTF0dDhoQT090/overview'

# UserAgent 
headers = {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e5752df-915a054873c751c475708940"
}

# Opening up connection to site
uClient = requests.get(my_url, headers=headers)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(uClient.content, 'html.parser')  
print(page_soup)
```

The interesting thing is, when I inspect the page I can see the data that I want to scrape but when I print the page in the code the data is not there. It seems that the data extracted is incomplete.

This is the piece of the data `<p id="warrantyExpiringLabel" class="mb-0">Expires  11 DEC. 2022</p>` that I want to see on my script but it's not there when printed.

I was reading some online forums saying that some data is inserted via javascript and that's why the Beautifulsoup lib can't extract it. I need to use some other lib to be able to gather the data.

I am still learning Python and Beautifulsoup lib so I may need someone to point me to the right direction.

Can anyone share your knowledge with me so I can learn this lib?

Comment: Check my answer that I have given to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587626/7994074. I hope this helps

Comment: The content you are trying to scrape is rendered dynamically with Javascript in the browser. With requests you only get the raw HTML without the paragraph you mention. You need to use sth like Selenium.

Comment: When you want to deal with Core Javascript based web Applications and want to make browser automation with AJAX/PJAX Requests. then Selenium would be a great choice.

Comment: Hey @petezurich Can you teach me how you know that the content is delivered dynamically via Javascript so I can learn as well and avoid the same mistake in the future?

Comment: In your browser you can compare the raw HTML (`View Page Source`) and the rendered web page content (`Inspect element`). The former is what you can get with requests, the latter is what you have to get with Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cadhs1/product-support/servicetag/0-NE9lVXI4NlpmbjFtRHJBbTF0dDhoQT090/overview")

time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("p", id="warrantyExpiringLabel"):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Expires  20 JUL 2023
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for fixing my code. I've been banging my head for a whole week. You even included the "headless" option so the web browser won't open while the code is running. This was perfect. 

I guess my mistake was trying to do this only using BeautifulSoup whereas I should've used selenium to make this work.

You are a legend!